# Javascript Parsing of the 'history.back()' stack to eliminate in-page appended navigation id(s)

Tags: css

Please, I use a small fixed [btm right of page] pair of buttons (an up and a down) for in-page navigation. I also have a larger return arrow with the code snippet below meant to go back to the previous html page menu:

```
<div id="Div-icon-returnback-indiv" class="IconOpacityControl-p5">
    <a href="#Previous" onclick="history.back();">
    <img id="icon-returnback-indiv" src="./Button-PREVIOUS-AD151D-E.png" alt="Previous"/></a>
</div>
```

Emanating from the parent page and intended return to page of
[eg.] http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Menu%20-%20Rivers%20of%20Mind%20and%20Heart.html

the problem then develops on the child page when its up or down buttons are used. Using them effectively adds my associated id(s) of #Top and #Bottom to the initial child page URL string of [ie]:

http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Poetry%20-%20Alive%20and%20Living%20in%20this%20Body.html

and it thus becomes appended as a new 'history' entry of [ie.]
http://gladheart.royalwebhosting.net/Poetry%20-%20Alive%20and%20Living%20in%20this%20Body.html#Bottom

There could, if the child page up and down arrows are used more than once, even then be more than one unwished for '#'(id) ending up being stacked in 'history.back'. Is it possible to javascript parse the stack until the first result that is free of any '#'(id) string at the end of the path [in my case specifically eliminating '#Top' and/or '#Bottom' if it makes it easier and dealing with the original unappended URL of the of the child page being navigated up and down on] to then use that result in the above 'onclick="history.back()' code snippet I am presently using to send it back to the parent html page where it really came from, not the top or bottom of the current child page?

As I commented below, perhaps @Will Peavy 's suggestion [in another thread] of 'document.referrer' (instead of 'history.back') might be the shortcut silver bullet if I used the correct syntax dragon. In my above code snippet, I have tried to no avail substituting the syntax of:

```
<!-- failure -->
<a href="#Previous" onclick="document.referrer();">
<!-- failure -->
```

Comment: I have tried using @Will Peavy 's suggestion [in another thread] of 'document.referrer'; but, and its probably due to my large knowledge gap of syntax when it comes to javascript, to no avail coded as: <a href="#Previous" onclick="document.referrer();">

Comment: You can’t do both anchor and a link, to go back simply use <a href=“javascript:history.go(-1)”>go back</a>

Comment: Thank you @bestinamir. The pure html link ..... <a href="#Previous" onclick="history.back();">.... passes w3c; and, works if the in-page navigation buttons were not activated. Switching to the javascriipt you indicated would not, unless my lack of javascript depth is missing something that should be obvious to a non-novice, seem to fully cover the situation where the in-page navigation buttons may be used not at all, once, or more than once? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You can use <a href=“#” onclick=“history.go(-1)”>go back</a> I have gaps too may be you can provide a link to w3c page where this is considered non compliant.. thanks

Comment: Thank you again @bestinamir. I have carefully inserted your code suggestions and they remain problematic. My comment regarding w3c [which does not evaluated javascript entries] did not refer to your code, but rather my initial code as I posted it in framing the question I asked.